# Cmake can not find ZLIB on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, zlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows Subsystem for linux. Cmake is version 3.16.3.
I am trying to build a project with a zlib dependency, and I get the following error...

```
 Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY) (found version "1.2.11")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:115 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:1224 (find_package)
```

The line of code referenced in the error is as follows...

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
```

package zlib1g is installed. How can I rectify this?

Comment: Please add your CMake code to your question post, as *text*.

Comment: According to https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.16.3/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake#L115 it seems like ZLib *binary* was not found whereas ZLib directory was found. I assume possible reasons might be different name conventions for Linux (**libz.a**) and Windows (**zlib.lib**).

Comment: @triclosan: Under WSL Windows-specific libraries (`.lib`, `.dll`) are never used.

Comment: "package zlib1g is installed." - Do you have [zlib1g-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/zlib1g-dev/filelist) package to be installed as well? Exactly this package provides library files like `libz.so` and `libz.a`. What is content of `ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR` CMake variable? (you may find that variable in `CMakeCache.txt` file in the build directory).

Comment: I got the same error and needed to rename `zlibwapi.lib` into `zlib.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

I met the same issue when built other libraries. Just install `zlib1g-dev` solved my problem.